# Design Considerations for comparator with ~1mV accuracy?

Tags: adc, noise, comparator

I am working on building an "exploded" analog to digital converter (ADC) (tracking type: up-down counting) for teaching purposes.

I am working with a 0-5V reference, and 12-bits of precision (values 0 to 4095). This range gives me about 1.2-2mV per "step." The design is based on a clock in the range of 10-20kHz.

I was considering using a hysteresis mode on my comparator to set a threshold, except  hysteresis only works for a certain fixed threshold voltage, and obviously the ADC needs a continuous, changing reference from the analog input signal.

What alternative design considerations, instead of a hysteresis, could I incorporate to minimize error (from noise) while accurately detecting these small changes in voltage?

Comment: Maxim has comparators with no hysteresis that are stable in the linear region. Kinda pricey but removes some thinking.

Comment: Are you referring to some of their "Zero" & "Ultra low Offset" (~10uV VOS) op-amps?

Comment: No, I am referring to their op amps that "have no minimum slew rate". The MAX9010-MAX9013, MAX912-MAX913, and MAX915-MAX916 are some. I don't know if it is really what you need, but it might give you some more room to work with so you don't get locked down by hysteresis.

Comment: Thank you for the part number. I'm not sure it would help as I am using a relatively "slow" clock of only 20kHz. But given your suggestion simply going with a higher-end opamp may be the most efficient solution price aside.

Comment: Well, the high-speed nature of those op-amps isn't what I thought you might be interested in. It's the fact that they are stable in the linear region where most other comparators would either be unstable without hysteresis that I thought you could be of use to you.

Comment: This is a good time to appreciate that even a lowly 12-bit ADC is pretty darn impressive.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQRzAo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The classic way around this is to put a D/A converter on the ADC output, but of *opposite polarity* to the input. Connect the input and output together via a voltage divider, and the comparator will be looking at zero volts when the ADC output is correct. Feed the comparator with ground and the difference signal, not the two voltages. Since the comparator is always triggering at the same voltage, you can set up hysteresis easily.

Comment: good point, but the topology has to change

Answer (score 0):

I would consider installing a pre-amplifier, to place the comparator and its rail bouncing (caused as the logic output flips state) away from the summing-node (or compare method) of your ADC. The ESD diodes inside the comparator, of size approximately 3 pF, will couple all GND upsets and all VDD upsets of the comparator directly to the comparator input pins.

Thus place just about any opamp (this is for 100Us or 50uS decision times, right?) with at least 1MHz UGBW, into a gain of 10 configuration.

With gain-of-10 the "opamp preamp" has bandwidth of 100 KHz, and settling time of 1.6uS; for 16 bits (over-designing), and knowing one neper is 8.6dB or about 1.6 bits, you need about 10 TAU or 16uS settling time.

By the way, you need to design the VDD for the preamp to be separate from the Comparator VDD, otherwise any shared VDD will be a path for oscillation.

Thus a ADC topology like this will let you retain your TWO NODES that vary 0--5v. Another way is to generate a summing node with 2 resistors, but that requires a negative-Vout of the DAC.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUvrNc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>